# Installing all the wheel packages in a directory is not working in Windows OS

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to clone all the packages of a venv from one PC to another(both having Windows OS). When I'm installing all the wheel packages on the second PC with this command

> pip install *.whl

as suggested by AKX in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63932038/7344164) to my question, it's giving me the error as.

> *.whl looks like a file but not found in the current directory.

When I installed a package that have no dependencies, it's installed successfully.
There is a long list of packages, so I can't install each package by typing the name of whole .whl file.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a helpful report, show the output you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a `bash` shell (Git Bash, Cygwin, WSL, or whatever), the following script works great:

```sh
for wheel in *.whl do
    pip install $wheel
done
```

I'm sure similar syntax could be used for Powershell.

Comment: OK Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to tell the pip to look for any dependencies of a package being installed, in the wheels directory?

Comment: As the second problem is, if a whl package have some dependencies, pip look for online packages but my machine don't have an internet connection(it's a remote PC), but all the dependencies are present in wheels folder.

Comment: @DevLoverUmar check out the [`pip` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io). It has a ton of options, and I'm pretty sure there's a way to do what you want to do.